# Data does not persist on the Webpage when i run the script multiple times

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am automating a website and giving data from a feature file. I am able to enter all the data(for a order) and click on submit button for the first time. If I run the same script for the same loan multiple times, I see the data on the webpage is not saved for couple of fields. I am using selenium with java and running the script on firefox browser.

> driver.findelement(By.xpath("").clear();
>
> driver.findelement(By.xpath("").sendKeys();
>
> driver.findelement(By.xpath("").click();

can somebody please help me on how to fix this issue..

Comment: Can you include your feature file? You mentioned it is not saving the data, so the relevant data is being entered properly?

Comment: You should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait for element present on the DOM before interaction to these elements...:)

Comment: Thanks for your response.. the data is being entered when the script is running but when I open the application to check if the data is in there.. I do not see it. this is happening intermittently. is there a sure shot way to make sure the data is persistent on the web app.